# UITableview loads data from Firebase and duplicate rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build an app that is loading data from firebase-database.

Saving members to Firebase is working without any problems. Load members from Firebase to my `UITableView` is working then I am sorting the members and add respectively member under sections header according to first names first letter(A, B, C, etc as seen in iOS contact app) and this is working as well however my **problem** occur after I have loaded all my users and for example go to Tab 1 and then switch back to Members Tab all displayed members/cells are duplicated. If I repeat the same procedure switching tabs back and forth all cells triplicate and it goes on.

I have searched different sources for a solution but I can not find anything that is similar.

Does anyone know a solution or what I an doing wrong?

Thanks!

**My Viewcontroller:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MembersTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var FBref = FIRDatabaseReference()

var members: [Member] = []
var membersDict = [String: [String]]()
var memberSectionTitles = [String]()

// TODO: Implement user.
//var user: AdminUser!
let fakeuservariable = "fakeuser"

@IBOutlet var memberListTableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    loadDataFromFirebase()
    createFirstnameDict()

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return memberSectionTitles.count

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let firstLetterKey = memberSectionTitles[section]
    if let firstnameValues = membersDict[firstLetterKey] {

        return firstnameValues.count
    }
    return 0

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return memberSectionTitles[section]

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "membercell", for: indexPath)

    let firstLetterKey = memberSectionTitles[indexPath.section]
    if let firstnameValues = membersDict[firstLetterKey] {

        cell.textLabel?.text = firstnameValues[indexPath.row]

    // Not working
    //let memberDetails = members[indexPath.row]
    //cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Amount left: \(memberDetails.memberamount)"

    }

    return cell

}

func createFirstnameDict() {

    for firstname in members {

        var firstLetter = firstname.firstname

        let firstnameKey = firstLetter.substring(to: firstLetter.characters.index(firstLetter.startIndex, offsetBy: 1))
        if var memberValues = membersDict[firstnameKey] {
            memberValues.append(firstLetter)
            membersDict[firstnameKey] = memberValues
        } else {
            membersDict[firstnameKey] = [firstLetter]

        }

    }

    memberSectionTitles = [String](membersDict.keys)
    memberSectionTitles = memberSectionTitles.sorted { $0 < $1 }

}

func loadDataFromFirebase() {

    let FBref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    FBref.child("member-list").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var resultItem: [Member] = []
        for item in snapshot.children {
            let memberItem = Member(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            resultItem.append(memberItem)

        }

        self.members = resultItem

        self.createFirstnameDict()

        self.tableView.reloadData()


    }) { (error) in

        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }

}

}
```

**My Member model:**

```
import Foundation

struct Member {

let firstname: String
let lastname: String
let email: String
let phonenumber: String
let socialsecuritynr: String
let memberamount: String
let addedByUser: String
let key: String
let ref: FIRDatabaseReference?

init(firstname: String, lastname: String, email: String, phonenumber: String, socialsecuritynr: String, memberamount: String, addedByUser: String, key: String = "") {
    self.key = key
    self.firstname = firstname
    self.lastname = lastname
    self.email = email
    self.phonenumber = phonenumber
    self.socialsecuritynr = socialsecuritynr
    self.memberamount = memberamount
    self.addedByUser = addedByUser
    self.ref = nil

}

init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    firstname = snapshotValue["firstname"] as! String
    lastname = snapshotValue["lastname"] as! String
    email = snapshotValue["email"] as! String
    phonenumber = snapshotValue["phonenumber"] as! String
    socialsecuritynr = snapshotValue["socialsecuritynr"] as! String
    memberamount = snapshotValue["memberamount"] as! String
    addedByUser = snapshotValue["addedByUser"] as! String
    ref = snapshot.ref
}

func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    return ["firstname": firstname, "lastname": lastname, "email": email, "phonenumber": phonenumber, "socialsecuritynr": socialsecuritynr, "memberamount":memberamount, "addedByUser": addedByUser]

}

}
```

**This is my TableView before and after:**

[image: TableView before and after]

Comment: Did you removed or detach the EventListner? If not, remove it to not get the duplicates

Comment: @Muhammad Farrukh Faizy I am not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I recommend you, is that you clear all your arrays that you populate on your before event listener. This way you make sure that when it come back from another view it will not have old data. Something like this:

```
self.members.removeAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is arising from the placement of your methods that load the data which are wrongly in viewDidAppear:

```
loadDataFromFirebase()
createFirstnameDict()
```

This means that each time your view appears your data is loaded again and again. To fix the problem move these methods into viewDidLoad and you wont get the duplication issues. So you should now have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadDataFromFirebase()
    createFirstnameDict()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

}
```

Comment: I might be missing something but your answer seems not to be a solution to my problem. If I do as you are suggesting the data and createFirstnameDict() will only run once. When I add a new when the app is running the tableView will not update with the new data or sort the user in my table view. Even if I only run tableView.reloadData() itself after I have added a new user it won't be added to my table view without createFirstnameDict() so I believe I have done something wrong within this function does that make sense?

Comment: Then keep your method in viewDidAppear but before you load the data empty the array and dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying the data from **membersDict** in your **cell.textlabel** .
Each time your view(when you switch tabs) loads, it calls **loadDataFromFirebase()** .

Here, all the values get loaded again and get appended to your **membersValues** which you then store in **membersDict**.

A new instance of **membersDict** will not get created since you are not declaring them inside of **viewDidLoad()**. You have declared them inside the class but outside any function.

What append does is add an element at the end of the array. It does not overwrite the element. So if you have an array with two names, appending a name will make that your third name and not overwrite any existing names.

Each time you load the view, you are appending the names to an array that already consists of the names. This is what is causing the duplication.

Try printing the value of your **membersDict** or **membersValues**, to check if you are duplicating.

You can solve this by declaring an instance of **membersDict** locally such that an empty variable is created each time and use that to display data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding and experience,  you load firebase data in

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadFirebaseData()
    }
```

Your newly created data from any other view controller will appear on your table when you return to it, because your observers are still listening unless you have told them to stop listening when moving to other views.

Therefore, anytime new data appears in Firebase, your table will automatically display it.